# How to call function after setState() done

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a function like this.

```
export function Counter() {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const countUp = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
    }

    const countUpAndShow = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
        alert(count);
    }

    // I won't call after countUp function, call only countUpAndShow function.
    useEffect(() => {
        alert(count);
    },[count])

    return <div>
        <button onClick={countUp}>count up!</button>
        <button onClick={countUpAndShow}>show count!</button>
    </div>
}
```

I want to call `alert(count)` after `setCount()`.
but `alert(count)` not show count correctly.

then, I use `useEffect` like above. but I want to call `alert()` only `countUpAndShow` function.
how to solve it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve for this. I will suggest using a React ref to toggle a `show` "state" so it can live outside the React component lifecycle and React hook dependencies. I also suggest using functional updates when incrementing a counter state value as this will correctly update from any previous state versus the state the callback was enqueued in. In other words it avoids stale state enclosures.

```
function Counter() {
  const show = useRef(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const countUp = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  };

  const countUpAndShow = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
    show.current = true;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (show.current) {
      alert(count);
      show.current = false;
    }
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={countUp}>count up!</button>
      <button onClick={countUpAndShow}>show count!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-call-function-after-setstate-done]

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
export function Counter() {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const countUp = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
    }

    const countUpAndShow = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
        setShow(true)
        alert(count);
    }

    // I won't call after countUp function, call only countUpAndShow function.
    useEffect(() => {
        if(show) {
            alert(count);
            setShow(false);
        }
    },[show])

    return <div>
        <button onClick={countUp}>count up!</button>
        <button onClick={countUpAndShow}>show count!</button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: the effect should be dependant also on `count`

Comment: Not required for the current use case.

Comment: I agree with @thedude, and also add that `countUpAndShow` still includes the `alert(count);` that doesn't work.

Comment: Not required, but you should add `count` regardless. In fact, `ESLint gives you a big warning if you don't.